# Show empty elements in DOMNodeList object

Tags: php, curl, dom, domdocument

I need some help with my code as I have got a problem with parse the elements from the tags in the html source. When I try this:

```
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 $doc->loadHTML($html);
 $get_time = $doc->getElementById('date-time');
```

I will get the empty output. I have tried to use `date` and `time` like this:

```
$get_time = $doc->getElementsByTagName('date');
```

And

```
$get_time = $doc->getElementsByTagName('time');
```

When I try it, nothing have been working as I will get the return output like this:

```
DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )
```

Here is the html code:

```
["<a style='width: 149px;' data-time='6:00 am' </a><a style='width: 149px;' data-time='6:30 am' 
</a><a style='width: 149px; data-time='7:00 am' </a><a style='width: 149px; data-time='7:30 am' 
</a><a style='width: 99px; data-time='7:00 am' </a>"]
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
6:00 am
6:30 am
7:00 am
7:30 am
8:00 am
```

Here is the full code:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/GS?cid=1234'
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => '',
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 5,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
 ));

 $html = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);

 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 $doc->loadHTML($html);
 $get_time = $doc->getElementsByTagName('date-time');

 foreach($get_timeas $time)
 {
    echo $time;
 }
```

I dont really understand why it have not been working when I am using the function `getElementsByTagName` which it supposed to work but it didn't. Can you please show me an example how I could parse the tags `date-time`using with domdocument?

**EDIT:**

This is what I am getting when I use `var_dump` and `print_r`:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(10830) "
UEFA Europa League Highlights
Hoogtepunten van alle wedstrijden in de UEFA Europa League.7.0
Fox Sports doc
Dejan Curovic - DJ Superstar
Samenvatting
Samenvatting
Fox Sports doc
Alleen onder de Lat
Eredivisie Highlights
```

The date-time is not showing up unless you open html source.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you're getting JSON, not HTML.

Comment: Make sure you know what data you're trying to work with:  `var_dump($html)`.  I'm guessing it will show you a string, just as you posted.  You would then json_decode() it to get an array, then use the first element of the array.  ie, `$result=curl_exec($curl); $html=json_decode($result); $doc->loadHTML($html[0]);`

Comment: @TimMorton I am not sure if I am using JSON but I think I am using HTML. If I am using JSON, do you know how I could parse the content from the tag called `date-time`? if you could post an answer that would be great.

Comment: I hesitated to put an answer out there because I like to be absolutely sure the answer is correct.  (I hate downvoters...)

Comment: I'll put up an answer shortly...

Comment: The source is what we need to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example HTML has wrong formatting: it misses `<a>` closing bracket and some quotes in styles attributes. Beside this, if the html is correct, you can use an Xpath expression to query the HTML

```
$html = '
<a style="width: 149px;" data-time="6:00 am"></a>
<a style="width: 149px;" data-time="6:30 am"></a>
<a style="width: 149px;" data-time="7:00 am"></a>
<a style="width: 149px;" data-time="7:30 am"></a>
<a style="width: 99px;" data-time="7:00 am"></a>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// here the document is completed with the missed html tag (body etc.)
// print $doc->saveHTML() to analyze the document
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// query for attributes
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$res = $xpath->query("//@data-time");

// map attributes node values
$map = array();
foreach($res as $node) {
   $map[] = $node->value;
}

// expected results
var_dump($map);
```

Note that, if the HTML provided is not a valid html, the DOMDocument library does not clean/correct the HTML as the browser does, so you can have some parsing errors or some unexpected behavior.

If as in your example the square brackets are comprised in the result you need to transform the results (if it's a valid json you can parse it)

XPath syntax examples
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256122(v=vs.110).aspx

Snippet
https://repl.it/repls/ValuableMundaneConnection

Comment: Thank you, it is working great. Problem are now solved!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is coming in as json:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/GS?cid=1234'
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => '',
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 5,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
 ));

 $result = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);

 $html = json_decode($result);
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 $doc->loadHTML($html[0]);
 $get_time = $doc->getElementsByTagName('date-time');

 foreach($get_timeas $time)
 {
    echo $time;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for his. When I try it, it is still the same as what I have already tried. Any idea?

Comment: Is $get_timeas just a typo?  Check what $html is with var_dump or print_r.

Comment: It gave me an error so I have changed from `foreach(get_timeas $time)` to `foreach(get_time as $time)` but I still get the same results. when I use `var_dump($get_time);` it give me this: `object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }`. Any idea?

Comment: Please see I have updated in my question that I have edited where you can see when I try `var_dump($html);` with a return output.